# why this program in way of scanning elements for array in c stops in the third line and don't execute next lines?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3][4];
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
          printf("a[%d][%d]:",i+1,j+1);
          scanf("%d",a[i][j]);
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program stops in the third line and doesn't execute the next lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the compiler warning in your `scanf` function:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

So, using

```
 scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
```

instead of

```
 scanf("%d",a[i][j]);
```

This happens because `scanf` receives an address (pointer) to variable, and not the variable itself. adding `&` before variable name will refer to it's address